# Why no one thought of the concept of joins before the 70s?

Tags: linux, text-processing, history, join, sql

So, let me see if I have my history right:

- In 1976, the first system sold as an RDBMS was Multics Relational Data Store. I don't know if it had JOIN, but let's assume it did.
- The UNIX command `join` was released in 1979. It imitates SQL's JOIN but it works on plain text files.

So my question is. If `join` is relatively useful on plain text, why wasn't something like it developed before? Surely operating systems were dealing with plain text data and "tabular data" to some extent since the late 50s. And I'm sure at some point they would have found it useful to have a ready-made abstraction or tool to combine data from two different files in a meaningful way.

So, why didn't the concept emerge before? Are my rose-tinted glasses underestimating the cognitive overhead of joins, with all their Venn diagramness, that is only justifiable when the performance of a RDB is needed? Were people content with merging data in an ad-hoc way? Or was join indeed a stroke of genius?

Answer (score 1):

"*`join` is relatively useful on plain text*" - that's the flaw in your argument.

The command is completely useless for plain text files; as an example consider a plain text file containing lines such as this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Ut laoreet sapien massa, ac malesuada sem egestas quis.
Cras id euismod dolor.
Pellentesque scelerisque dolor orci, sit amet rutrum nunc condimentum vitae.
Vivamus tincidunt massa maximus volutpat auctor.
```

and one such as this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nam nec enim et felis sagittis suscipit porta eu erat.
Pellentesque scelerisque dolor orci,
sit amet rutrum nunc condimentum vitae.
Praesent tincidunt pulvinar est vitae laoreet.
```

On the other hand, it can be useful for semi-structured files, where key fields are identifiable as such, and separated from other data by a known character (string) such as <kbd>tab</kbd>. For example, these two *semi-structured* files could be applied with `join` in a meaningful fashion:

```
Apple   red
Banana  yellow
Orange  orange

red     5
yellow  3
orange  2
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I said "plain text" in my question, I meant files that use a standard encoding of characters, in opposition to the binary files that RDBMs use. In any case, my question was considering files like the one in your last example, as those are the kind of files that the `join` command is meant to work on.

Comment: @SebastianCarlos please make that clear in your question. As you can see I interpreted what you wrote in a different way to that which you intended. (Feel free to copy my examples, if that's useful.)

Comment: My question already clarifies it. It says "tabular data"

Comment: Not from where I sit, @SebastianCarlos. You wrote, "_operating systems were dealing with plain text data and "tabular data"_", with the implication that the "_plain text data_" is different to "_tabular data_"

Comment: I see no problem with that sentence from where I sit. The following is true:(1) the join command works on plain text
(2) plain text is different from tabular data
(3) tabular data can be plain text.

And if I'm asking about the join command concerning its SQL counterpart, I think people will likely assume that I understand that `join` is meant to work on tabular data.